# Newly Added Table missing in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am Using VS2013 and EF6.0 with MS SQL Server 2012. For EF6.0 I choosen

"Generate from Database". Then It brought all the table in the Database. Now I have Added new table called "LoginEntry" in same database. It is showing in SQL Server newly added table.

[image]

When I am trying update  EDMX file using "Update Model from Database" option, It shows the new table. but when i checked on the table and the options and click "Finish". It is not updating the EDMX as well in diagram also. I tried Many times. Can anyone suggest pls?

Comment: Close the Visual studio and then reopen new instance of it.After that do the same above and let us know about the result.

Comment: Still Nope. Tried many times closed and reopened both VS and Sql Server

Comment: can you create a new project and see that ?

Comment: i added new column in existing table. it s updated. But the new table alone is not getting updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Primary Key to the newly added table. Then it came to picture. Thank you guys for your suggestion